# Assertion failed on google maps polyline extraction and buffer

Tags: python, django, google-maps, shapely

I am working on a django project where the user inputs their start and end location in the form a string.

My application must connect to the google direction service API, take the string and convert it to coords. Then from the coordinates create a polyline, and add a 1km buffer. Which will be saved in a postgis database as a polygon.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields
import shapely.geometry
import googlemaps
from googlemaps import Client

# Create your models here.

class Route(models.Model):
    startPoint_address = PointField()
    startPoint_geolocation = Pointfield()
    endPoint_address = PointField()
    endPoint_geolocation = Pointfield()
    # endPoint = models.PointField()
    # deviationDistance = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    # routeName = models.CharField(max_length=50)




# https://github.com/geodav-tech/decode-google-maps-polyline
def decode_polyline(polyline_str):
    '''Pass a Google Maps encoded polyline string; returns list of 
    lat/lon pairs'''
    index, lat, lng = 0, 0, 0
    coordinates = []
    changes = {'latitude': 0, 'longitude': 0}

    # Coordinates have variable length when encoded, so just keep
    # track of whether we've hit the end of the string. In each
    # while loop iteration, a single coordinate is decoded.
    while index < len(polyline_str):
        # Gather lat/lon changes, store them in a dictionary to apply them later
        for unit in ['latitude', 'longitude']:
            shift, result = 0, 0

            while True:
                byte = ord(polyline_str[index]) - 63
                index+=1
                result |= (byte &  0x1f) << shift
                shift += 5
                if not byte >= 0x20:
                    break

            if (result & 1):
                changes[unit] = ~(result >> 1)
            else:
                changes[unit] = (result >> 1)

        lat += changes['latitude']
        lng += changes['longitude']

        coordinates.append((lat / 100000.0, lng / 100000.0))

    return coordinates

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='AIzaSyCetShZ10WQVBVPaIu9pdPEktRVQq78TF4')

google_directions = gmaps.directions("Stellenbosch", "Cape Town")
encoded_polyline = google_directions[0]['overview_polyline']['points']
decoded_polyline = decode_polyline(encoded_polyline)
shapely_line = shapely.geometry.LineString(decoded_polyline)
buffered_line = shapely_line.buffer(0.00001)
```

Current error: 
Assertion failed: (0), function query, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 287.
Abort trap: 6

Any assistance possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand you get the error in the line `shapely_line = shapely.geometry.LineString(decoded_polyline)`. So, all the django and google part is kind of irrelevant. I would be easier to help you if you post an example of the value in `encoded_polyline` variable.